# Texshop preview does not reload

Tags: lyx, texshop, preview

I am using Lyx with Texshop as my preview viewer.

I have the following problem: At random times, when I recompile my document using Lyx, all I get in the Texshop window is this:

[image]

In other words, the preview does not load. In order to fix this, I will have to quit and restart Texshop, until this happens again, randomly as it seems (I cannot reproduce the problem at will...)

If anyone has any idea about this issue, that would be really helpful!

I am on latest MacOS Mojave, latest Lyx (and Mactex), and latest Texshop.

Comment: This seems like more of a bug report than a question. It might be more appropriate to post on the [TeX-on-MacOS mailing list](https://email.esm.psu.edu/mailman/listinfo/macosx-tex) which is read by the TeXShop developers.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that as well.

Comment: I thought Lyx did its own display? Is TeXShop being used to typeset your document as well as Preview it? Do you have TeXShoop set up to be used with an external editor (`The On Startup section of the Source tab in TeXShop->Preferences`)? If TeXShop is only being used as a Previewer you might try using `Skim` instead.

Comment: Lyx does need a viewer, such as Adobe Reader, or Skim, or Texshop. I use Texshop because I like it, no other particular reason. To answer your other questions, Texshop is not used to typeset, only to preview. Also, I had not checked the "Configure for External Editor". I have checked that now. Do you think it might be that?

Comment: By the way, on my iMac at home everything works as it should, but I do not remember if I have checked the "Configure for External Editor" box. However, I have not upgraded to the latest Mojave yet, and this might play a role.